# Normalizing a family of plane curves containing a cusp

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

In Caporaso and Harris's paper (http://www.mat.uniroma3.it/users/caporaso/CaporasoHarrisInv.pdf page 368, right before section 3), it is mentioned that if $[X]$ is a point on the variety of plane curves with a given degree $d$ and genus $g$ such that $X$ has a cusp and $\delta-1=\binom{d-1}{2}-g-1$ nodes, then we cannot simultaneously normalize the fibers of the universal family $\mathscr{X}\subset V\times\mathbb{P}^2\rightarrow V$ in some neighborhood $V$ of $[X]$.

How do we see this? If it is easier to explain, how do we see this in just one example?